# ORA-0020: Maximum number of processes (150) exceeded

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I tried login into sql plus. When i enter the username and password as system it displays the message maximum number of processes (150) exceeded. How i could resolve this error.

Comment: Are you the DBA?  Do you expect there to be more than 150 processes and do you have the hardware to handle that many sessions?  The answer could be anything from increasing the `processes` parameter to configuring shared server/ MTS to limit the number of sessions that get created to killing a bunch of sessions that don't need to be there and configuring dead connection detection.

Comment: You should check _why_ you exceeded that limit. Problems like that are very often caused by bugs in programs not releasing connections properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a DBA or you have DBA rights you can do this as below:

Steps to increase the number for processes/sessions at database level in Oracle is as follows

```
  1.  Log on to the database as system administrator
```

> •  In SQL Plus enter: "connect / as sysdba"

```
  2. Set the number of processes to be desired value <num_processes>
```

> • In SQL Plus "alter system set processes={num_processes}
>   scope=spfile"

```
  3. Unset the number of sessions to remove the default session limit
```

> • In SQLPlus "alter system reset sessions scope=spfile sid='*' "

```
  4. Shutdown the database
```

> • In SQL Plus "shutdown immediate"

```
  5. Startup the database
```

> • In SQL Plus "startup"

```
   6. Check the changes have taken effect.
```

> • In SQL Plus "show parameter sessions" and "show parameter
>   processes"

or run the query `select value from v$parameter where name = 'processes'`

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e0.htm)

1.Login as sysdba

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

2.Check Current Setting of Parameters

```
sql> show parameter sessions
sql> show parameter processes
sql> show parameter transactions
```

3.If you are planning to increase "PROCESSES" parameter you should also plan to increase "sessions and "transactions" parameters
A basic formula for determining  these parameter values is as follows:

```
processes=x
sessions=x*1.1+5
transactions=sessions*1.1
```

4.These paramters can't be modified in memory. You have to modify the spfile only (scope=spfile) and bounce the instance.

```
sql> alter system set processes=500 scope=spfile;
sql> alter system set sessions=555 scope=spfile;
sql> alter system set transactions=610 scope=spfile;
sql> shutdown abort
sql> startup
```